# Derive from CObject for serialization results in a compiler error for access

Tags: c++, mfc, constructor, derived-class

I created my class `CData` and derived it from `CObject`, because I need to serialize it.

```
class CData : public CObject
{
    DECLARE_SERIAL(CData);
public:
    CData();
    virtual ~CData();
    virtual void Serialize(CArchive& ar);

    //Data
    CString m_strName;
    ULONG m_ulID;
    CString m_strCorps;
    CPoint m_Coordinate;
    short m_sStatus;
};
```

And I use a vector of type `vector<CData>` in my document class. I add new CData-objects to the vector during the runtime of the program using `vecData.push_back(Data)` (where Data is of type CData).

But when I try to compile this i get the following error:

> error C2248: 'CObject::CObject' : cannot access private member
>   declared in class 'CObject'

I searched a bit and found out, that it has to do with the CObject-class to be non-copyable or something like this!?!?...

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CObject` declares the copy constructor as `private`, so you need to implement the copy constructor (and assignment operator overload) for your class yourself. The [`CObject` constructor documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/st9cdfkz.aspx) says:

> The standard C++ default class copy constructor does a member-by-member copy. The presence of the private CObject copy constructor guarantees a compiler error message if the copy constructor of your class is needed but not available. You must therefore provide a copy constructor if your class requires this capability.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Did you happen to forget `IMPLEMENT_SERIAL` in the .cpp-file?